# PHP won't insert into MySQL, no error

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]', '$_POST[lastname]', '$_POST[username]', password('$_POST[password]'), 'Users', '', '', '$pchange', 
'$_POST[email]', '$default_url', '$verify', '', 0, '', 0)";

$result = @mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

$sql, $connection and $table_name are all valid and are used previously in the script and the database, this is how my database looks like:

```
firstname   varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
lastname    varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
username    varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
password    varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
group1      varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
group2      varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
group3      varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
pchange     varchar(1)  latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
email       varchar(100)latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
redirect    varchar(100)latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
verified    varchar(1)  latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
last_login  date                                Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
balance     double      UNSIGNED                Yes 0             Change      Drop   More 
address     varchar(60) latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL          Change      Drop   More 
lostbalance double                              Yes 0             Change      Drop   More
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use error suppressing operator if you want to see what's wrong.

Comment: echo $sql and see if you can run it manually inside mysql.

Comment: get rid of that `@`!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Also, don't just blindly insert $_POST variables into your mysql queries. Either `mysql_real_escape` them before or use prepared statements (PDO is great for this too).

Comment: I used if(!cleanQuery($_POST['username'])==$_POST['username']) before that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No error because of @:

```
@mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

The @ suppresses the errors from the mysql_query() function.

I see multiple errors in your statements:

1. `'$_POST[firstname]'`- is suppossed to be `$_POST['firstname']`. Store the value in a variable or use concatenation: `"'.$_POST['firstname'].'"`
2. Use `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`
3. Escape all the data you are storing in the db.

Comment: To further comment on this, read: [Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (Search for it on the page, it doesn't provide a direct link to that paragraph)

Comment: `"$_POST[firstname]"` is correct.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not good security practice to leave any user input unfiltered, because soon you will be victim of SQL injection and/or XSS attacks. You should filter your user input this way:

`$var = filter_var($_POST['var']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

Then you should use this `$var` in your SQL query, instead of directly using the `$_POST['var'].` i.e.:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name VALUES
('$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', password('$password'), 'Users', '', '', '$pchange', 
'$email', '$default_url', '$verify', '', 0, '', 0)";
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to name the table columns in front of "VALUES"

```
INSERT INTO $table_name (field_1, field2, ...) VALUES ($_POST_1, ...)
```

Comment: Only if the provided value count doesn't match the column count.